# My application can't show image on my home fragment even after my Toast says successfully added, no solution online has helped thus far

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is the home fragment code, it works fine and no errors at all the only issue is it won't publish and image to the home fragment page on my android emulator. checked online for useful tips but none has helped. Highly anticipating. Thanks

```
public class HomeFragment1 extends Fragment {

 RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
    PostAdapter postAdapter;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    List<Post> postList;



    public HomeFragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment1 fragment = new HomeFragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home1, container, false);
        postRecyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.postCT);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        postRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts");
        return fragmentView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //Get List Post
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                postList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot postSnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post post = postSnap.getValue(Post.class);
                    postList.add(post);
                }

                postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(),postList);
                postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Here is the XML for the fragment of the home to be displayed. There is row XML bounded to it that contains the image sample to be posted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.ui.home.HomeFragment1">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/postCT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the row the Home activity code removed some unnecessary code that does not link to the image uploading.

```
public class Home_PersonalActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{



    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Dialog popAddPost;
    ImageView popUpUserImage, popUpPostImage, popupAddBtn;
    TextView popUpTittle, popUpDescription;
    ProgressBar popUpProgressBar;
    private static final int PreqCode = 2;
    private static int REQUESCODE = 2;
    private Uri pickedPicUri = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home__personal);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser =  mAuth.getCurrentUser();




        // Initialize pop_up from the popup drawable xml
        initialisePopUp();

        setUpPopupImageClick();



            FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popAddPost.show();

         }
      });

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true); // This code here is for the hamburger sign that opens up the drawer
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();// this is for the opening and closing and normalization of the hamburger sign

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        updateNavHeader();

        // Set the home fragment as default entry point when user logs in
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment1()).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
      //  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment1()).commit();

//        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
//        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
//        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
//                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_logout)
//                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
//                .build();
//        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
//        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
//        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

  } 
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home__personal, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment1()).commit();



        } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Profile");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new ProfileFragment1()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new SettingFragment1()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent LoginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), loginActivity.class);
            startActivity(LoginActivity);
            finish();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

    public void updateNavHeader(){

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView navUsername = headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_UserName);
        TextView navUserMail = headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_UserMail);
        ImageView navUerPic = headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_UserPhoto);


        navUserMail.setText(currentUser.getEmail());
        navUsername.setText(currentUser.getDisplayName());


        // Using glide to load user image
        Glide.with(this).load(currentUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(navUerPic);

    }
}
```

Here is the XML of the image I am to upload

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_imageID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/small"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/row_post_imageID"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/row_post_imageID"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/black_gradient" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_tittle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/row_post_userProfImg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_userProfImg"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tiny"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.567"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun they say in the question body that there is no error - it just doesn't show their image

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at `postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(),postList);`, is the `postList` empty?

Comment: Just a suggestion remove all the redundant code from your fragment class.

Comment: @lucidbrot the postList contains the model getters and setters

Comment: I don't see anything in the given code that does anything with any images. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I have done that @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I finally solved it by rearranging my post XML files to the code below, they were pretty messed up, and it fixed the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_imageID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/row_post_imageID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/black_gradient" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_tittle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/row_post_userProfImg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_userProfImg"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```